# Elasticsearch range query on list of object

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range-query

here my mapping

```
{             "seoSubscribedFlag": {"type": "boolean"},
            "seoSubscribedExpiryDate": {"type": "date"},
            "userActive" :{"type" : "boolean"},
            "emailVerified" :{"type" : "boolean"},
            "isOnLineShodAdded" :{"type" : "boolean"},
            "productList" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "prodId" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "prodName" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "brand" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "modelNo" : {"type" : "string"},

                    "grossAmt" : {"type" : "float"},
                    "netAmt" : {"type" : "float"},
                    "prodDesc" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "prodKeyFeatures" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "prodSize" :{ "type": "nested" }

                }
            }
        }
```

here my josn

```
{
"userId": "2",  
"seoSubscribedFlag": true,
"seoSubscribedExpiryDate": 1501312549,
"userActive" : true,
"emailVerified" : true,
"isOnLineShodAdded" : false,
"productList" : {
    "properties" : {
        "prodId" : "2",            
        "netAmt" : 50,            
        "prodSize" :["XS","XL"]

    }
}
}
```

i want to search data with BOOL MUST based on product netAmt ,
Like netAmt Must in between 10 to 60
i try BOOL MUST RANGE but it not work with list of object
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "productList.netAmt": {
            "gt": 10,
            "lt": 60
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer to ES [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-range-query.html)

Comment: Hi true, but Bool Must Range not work with list of object

Comment: @Amar Gohil  It should work.  Could you provide your mappings?

Comment: @Zhitoa Yue  here it is....      "isOnLineShodAdded" :{"type" : "boolean"},
                "productList" : {
                    "properties" : {
                       
                       
                       
                        
                        "grossAmt" : {"type" : "float"},
                        "netAmt" : {"type" : "float"},
                       
                       
                        "prodSize" :{ "type": "nested" }
                        
                    }
                }

Comment: I just saw your sample data like this `"productList" : {
    "properties" : {
        "prodId" : "2",            
        "netAmt" : 50,            
        "prodSize" :["XS","XL"]

    }
}`  Could you change it to `"productList" : {
    "prodId" : "2",            
    "netAmt" : 50,            
    "prodSize" :["XS","XL"]
}`  You don't need add `properties` when putting data

Comment: i cant added data without properties give me Error like this         object mapping for [productList.prodSize] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value